# Image name is not saved in database codeigniter 3

Tags: database, image, upload, codeigniter-3

here I am adding attach file input in the add_incident form, but after submitting form the file name is not saved in the database and also the file is not saved in upload folder.the uploads folder path is correct. running

```
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_FILES);
    die;
```

Output is:

> Array
> (
> [filename] => Array
> (
> [name] => mot-testing-station 2.eps
> [type] => application/postscript
> [tmp_name] => /opt/lampp/temp/phpMSzQT6
> [error] => 0
> [size] => 405159
> )
> )

but it doesn't give any output and it just continue to submit the form and create new incident.

can anyone please help me what am I missing ?

view.php

```
 <h2 class="heading">Add Incidents</h2>
   <?php echo form_open_multipart('incidents_add'); ?>
    <div class="row">
           <div class="form-group col-md-4">
              <label for="email">Incidents ID</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="T_id" placeholder="Name" name="T_id"value="<?php echo $T_id;?>" readonly >
            </div>
           <div >
             <input id = "choose_image" type="file" name="filename" size="20" />
           </div>
           
       <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="btn-section float-right">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" value="Create"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Create</button>
        </div>
    </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

controller.php

```
function add()
  { 
  $existing_count = $this->incidents_model->get_task_count();
  $data['T_id']  = 'T'.sprintf("%'.03d\n",$existing_count+1);
 
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('Status', 'Status ', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('Priority', 'Priority' , 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('Description', 'Description' , 'required');
  
  $data['incidents'] = $this->incidents_model->getIncidentsDetails();
  $data['T_id'] = $this->incidents_model->get_task_count();
  $data['company_name'] = $this->incidents_model->getAllCompanyName();

  if (isset($_FILES['filename'])){ 
    // print_r($_FILES);
    //     die;
    
      $file_name = time().'_'.$_FILES['filename']['name'];
      $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
      $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|dox|pdf';
      $config['max_size']             = 100;
      $config['max_width']            = 1024;
      $config['max_height']           = 768;

      $config['file_name']          = $file_name; 


      $this->load->library('upload', $config);

      $this->upload->initialize($config);

      if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('filename'))
      {
              $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
              $this->load->view('admin/incidents/add', $error);
      }
      else
      {
              $data = array('file' =>$this->upload->data());
              $this->load->view('admin/incidents/add', $data);
        }
  }

  if ($this->form_validation->run() ==true)
  {
    $this->incidents_model->add(); 
    $this->session->set_flashdata ('success','Incidents Added Sucessfully');
    redirect('admin/incidents/index' ,$data);
  }
  else{
    $this->load->view('admin/incidents/add', $data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is how I solved the issue, I have added

```
$data['file'] = $this->incidents_model->add($image_name);
```

and that solved my issue.

controller:

```
    function add()
  { 
  $existing_count = $this->incidents_model->get_task_count();
  $data['T_id']  = 'T'.sprintf("%'.03d\n",$existing_count+1);
  
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('T_id', 'Tasks Id', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('Tname', 'Tasks Name' , 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('Cname', 'Company Name ', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('Pname', 'Project Name' , 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('Pversion', 'Project Version', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('Rform', 'Report Form ', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('Internal', 'Internal ', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('Assignto', 'Assign To' , 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('Sdate', 'Start Date', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('Edate', 'End Date' , 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('Status', 'Status ', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('Priority', 'Priority' , 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('Description', 'Description' , 'required');
  
  $data['incidents'] = $this->incidents_model->getIncidentsDetails();
  $data['T_id'] = $this->incidents_model->get_task_count();
  $data['company_name'] = $this->incidents_model->getAllCompanyName();
if ($this->form_validation->run() ==true)
  {

  if (isset($_FILES['filename']))
  { 
    // echo "<pre>";
    //     print_r($_FILES);
    //     die;
    
      $file_name = time().'_'.$_FILES['filename']['name'];
      $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
      $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|dox|pdf';
      $config['max_size']             = 100;
      $config['max_width']            = 1024;
      $config['max_height']           = 768;
      $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
      $config['file_name']          = $file_name; 
      
      $this->load->library('upload', $config);

      $this->upload->initialize($config);

      if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('filename'))
      {
              $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
              $this->load->view('admin/incidents/add', $error);
      }
      else
      {
            $image_data = $this->upload->data();
                        $image_name  =  $image_data['file_name'];
                         $data =array(
                          'file' => $image_data['file_name']
            );
               $data['file'] = $this->incidents_model->add($image_name);

        }
   }
    $this->session->set_flashdata ('success','Incidents Added Sucessfully');
    redirect('admin/incidents/index' ,$data);
  }
  else{
    $this->load->view('admin/incidents/add', $data);
  }
}
```

and modified my add function in model as below:

```
 function add()
{
    $arr['incidents_id'] = $this->input->post('T_id');
    $arr['incident_name'] = $this->input->post('Tname');
    $arr['company_name'] = $this->input->post('Cname');
    $arr['project_name'] = $this->input->post('Pname');
    $arr['project_version'] = $this->input->post('Pversion');
    $arr['report_form'] = $this->input->post('Rform');
    $arr['internal'] = $this->input->post('Internal');
    $arr['assign_to'] = $this->input->post('Assignto');
    $arr['start_date'] = $this->input->post('Sdate');
    $arr['end_date'] = $this->input->post('Edate');
    $arr['status'] = $this->input->post('Status');
    $arr['priority'] = $this->input->post('Priority'); 
    $arr['description'] = $this->input->post('Description');
    $arr['initial_status'] = 0 ;
    $arr['flag'] = 1;
    $arr['file'] = time().'_'.$_FILES['filename']['name']; 
    
    $this->db->insert('incidents',$arr);
    $insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
    $arr1['incident_id'] = $insert_id;
    $arr1['incident_status'] = $this->input->post('Status');
    $arr1['incident_description'] = $this->input->post('Description');
    $this->db->insert('incident_status',$arr1);
}
```